# rolling с заданным шагом

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет! Есть скрипт, который при помощи rolling ищет в столбце максимальное значение. Текущий шаг окна =1, то есть последовательность скольжения `(1,3,1)` далее `(3,1,5)` и т.д

Как можно задать шаг = 3, то есть последовательность будет `(1,3,1)` и `(5,10,5)`?

На скриншоте указано движение окна и красным выделены максимумы, которые скрипт в итоге должен вывести.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел вариант `df.rolling(window=3,step=3)`, но он не работает...

```
import pandas as pd
sample = {
    'ID':[1,1,1,9,9,9],
    'Quant' :[1,3,1,5,10,5]
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(sample)

df2=df.rolling(3).agg({'Quant':'max'})
df3=df2.dropna(how='all')
print(df3)
```

Comment: все работает прекрасно. если у вас возникает ошибка, приведите ее в вопросе.

Comment: добавил в сообщение скриншот

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неверно понимаете работу метода rolling. Судя по описанию задачи, он вам вообще не подходит. я бы порекомендовал сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sample = {
    'ID':[1,1,1,9,9,9],
    'Quant' :[1,3,1,5,10,5]
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(sample)
step = 3

res = [x.Quant.max() for x in np.array_split(df, len(df)//step)]
print(res)
```

> [3, 10]

То есть, с помощью `np.array_split` вы разбиваете датафрейм не куски нужной длины, а потом в каждом куске ищите максимум колонки `Quant`.

Answer (score 2):

еще так можно получить нужные максимумы:

```
res = [df.iloc[i:i+3,1].max() for i in range(0,len(df),3)]
'''
[3, 10]
```

или чтобы отфильтровать нужные строки:

```
res = df.iloc[[df.iloc[i:i+3,1].idxmax() for i in range(0,len(df),3)]]
'''
   ID  Quant
1   1      3
4   9     10
```